# How to in general convert classes to xml nodes?

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, json, class

I want some Generic way to convert objects to xml nodes :

if i have some `xml nodes` like this:

```
<BusinessObject xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/bpm/bpmobject/Data/BusinessObject">&lt;?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
&lt;BusinessObject xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  &lt;attribute1>sss&lt;/attribute1>
  &lt;attribute2>sss&lt;/attribute2>
&lt;/BusinessObject></BusinessObject>
```

---

I convert it to `Json` like that

```
 {
    "-xmlns": "http://xmlns.oracle.com/bpm/bpmobject/Data/BusinessObject",
    "#text": "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-16\"?>
<BusinessObject xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\">
  <attribute1>sss</attribute1>
  <attribute2>sss</attribute2>
</BusinessObject>"
}
```

---

Then to c# class:

```
public class Rootobject
    {
        public string xmlns { get; set; }
        public string text { get; set; }
    }
```

Now how to reverse it to xml nodes again after setting its value ? I want a general solution not for this example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[XML serialization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/182eeyhh%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) is what you are looking for

```
     public class Rootobject
     {
        public string xmlns { get; set; }
        public string text { get; set; }
     }



    public static void Main(string[] args) 
    { 
      Rootobject details = new Rootobject();
      details.xmlns = "myNamespace";
      details.text = "Value";

      Serialize(details);
   }   

   static public void Serialize(Rootobject details)
   { 
     XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Rootobject)); 
     using (TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Xml.xml"))
     {
       serializer.Serialize(writer, details); 
     } 
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**XML Serialization**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/182eeyhh%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) for converting a `Class` to `XML`, and viceversa.

For reference, read [C# Tutorial - XML Serialization](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/csharp-tutorial-xml-serialization).

You can also refer to [XML Schema Definition Tool](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x6c1kb0s(v=vs.80).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

**Example:**

```
[DataContract]
public class MyClass1 {
    [DataMember]
    public string name;
    [DataMember]
    public int age;
}
```

**Serialize / Deserialize**

```
MyClass1 obj = new MyClass1();
DataContractSerializer dcs = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(MyClass1));

    using (Stream stream = new FileStream(@"C:\tmp\file.xml", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
    {
        using (XmlDictionaryWriter writer = 
            XmlDictionaryWriter.CreateTextWriter(stream, Encoding.UTF8))
        {
            writer.WriteStartDocument();
            dcs.WriteObject(writer, obj);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to apply the Serializable attribute to your class to be able to serialize it. This makes sure that your class does not use some none serializable attributes.

```
[Serializable]
public class Rootobject
{
    public string xmlns { get; set; }
    public string text { get; set; }
}
```